# How to retrieve analytics data from firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-analytics, flutter-windows

I want to retrieve the analytics data stored in firebase(like users in last 30 minutes, events triggered, sales made etc) in a flutter windows application i am creating. I know how to send data to firebase but i want to retrieve this analytics data so i can view it in my flutter windows app. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: While there *is* an API to get analytics data these days, it is not callable from client-side applications like your Flutter app. I linked some questions with answers that show what *is* possible.