# Is there any API to get firebase analytics in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-analytics

Is there any API to show  firebase `analytics` in the `flutter` app?

Comment: So if I understand correctly you would like to show the data obtained from your app's analytics in an app?

Comment: yes..i want to display firebase analytics in my flutter app

Comment: Search is your friend here: https://www.google.com/search?q=Is+there+any+API+to+show+firebase+analytics+in+the+flutter+app%3F, and from there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71230923/how-to-retrieve-analytics-data-from-firebase-in-flutter. The API that allows retrieval is REST based, so you can call it from almost any platform (including Flutter).

Comment: @HizbaMehwish please find the answer below. It will helpful and mark its useful

Answer (score 0):

**Firebase Analytics Integration**

Create a new class with the name `FirebaseAnalyticsService`

```
import ‘package:firebase_analytics/firebase_analytics.dart’;

import ‘package:firebase_analytics/observer.dart’;

class FirebaseAnalyticsService {

final FirebaseAnalytics _analytics = FirebaseAnalytics();

FirebaseAnalyticsObserver appAnalyticsObserver() =>

FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: _analytics);}
```

Now register this class in our `servicelocator` file:

```
serviceLocator.registerLazySingleton(() => FirebaseAnalyticsService());
```

reference: https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/how-to-add-firebase-analytics-to-your-flutter-app-641fbda1d224

Answer (score 0):

You may consider [Google Analytics Data API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1) which gives you programmatic access to Google Analytics 4 (GA4) report data. Note that data isn't in realtime and reporting also undergoes delays in processing as described in this [blog post](https://firebase.blog/posts/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up).